# ng-repeat based on model value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to repeat a piece of html based on value of my model. If a user select "3" at the dropdown, it will display "1,2,3" each one on it's own div. After that, if user changes the dropdown to 2, then it should render only "1,2".

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>teste</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='testController'>
        <select ng-model="quantity">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

        <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(quantity) track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</div>

        Value on Model:{{quantity}}

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("app",[]);
            app.controller('testController',['$scope', function($scope){

                $scope.quantity = 1;

                $scope.getNumber = function (num) {
                    return new Array(num);
                };

            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Until now, it's not working the render part based on model value. What am I misising?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [limitTo filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) is the most idiomatic way to do this

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.values=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='testController'>
        <select ng-model="quantity">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

        <div ng-repeat="i in values | limitTo:quantity">{{i}}</div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.getNumber = function (num) {
     return new Array(parseInt(num));
};`

also works from your code

Answer (score -1):

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>teste</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='testController'>
        <select ng-model="quantity" ng-change="changed()">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

        <div ng-repeat="i in values track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</div>

        Value on Model:{{quantity}}

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("app",[]);
            app.controller('testController',['$scope', function($scope){

                $scope.quantity = 1;
                $scope.values = [1]

                $scope.getNumber = function (num) {
                    return new Array(num);
                };

                $scope.changed = function() {
                  $scope.values = new Array(parseInt($scope.quantity));
                }

            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. Could you explain why should I use a "changed" function?

Comment: introduced ng-change for select. Also new field in controller, which will be changed in ng-change function and will be used in ng-repeat

Comment: Sorry, I didnt read your question properly. Your actual problem is num in getNumber function is string and you cannot create array with that. You could just use parseInt and use that for creating array. - ypu dont need to use changed event. :)

Comment: Also using functions inside ng-repeat is bad idea (performance issues for large arrays). Which is why I have introduced a ng-change function and use variable inside ng-repeat